# unicode in joined string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode-escapes

```
for x in range(0,10):
    v=f'{x:0=4}'
    print('\u' + v)
```

File "ipython-input-47-976d3b5794b6", line 3
    print('\u' + v)
         ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \uXXXX escape

I don't understand why this doesn't work. If I have the basic items e.g. '\u0000'or '\u0001' etc. and print then that works. But trying to make a string from 2 parts seems to be a problem.

I am going from 0 to 9 and creating a string in a field of 4 characters with a fill of '0' and then adding the unicode escape to the string.

Edit:19feb2019
Basically I wanted:

```
for x in range(0,10):
    print(chr(x))
```

I've learned that unicode string literals in python are strange things.
This page describes some aspects of the problem space - https://www.pythonsheets.com/notes/python-unicode.html.
unicode string literal

index 0 of the unicode string literal

cli- '\u0006'[0]

Out[29]: '\x06'

unicode string literal index on character 3 is an error

cli- '\u0006'[2]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "ipython-input-30-3fb346b8fd83", line 1, in 
    '\u0006'[2]

IndexError: string index out of range

Edit:20feb2019

éééé

How many characters does éééé equal?

This is the first time I noticed that in my editor (textpad) that it takes 2 right arrows to go through a single character. At the end of éééé the file position is 9, it starts at 1 and ends at 9.